# I dont have bcrypt in my project but i have an error with it

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, node-modules, bcrypt

I have an error - Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'.
But i dont use bcrypt in my project, i use bcryptjs.
Also, when i installed bcrypt, it automatically deleted in few minutes(i think, it was deleted when I install another package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install a specific version of bcrypt.

```
npm i --save bcrypt@3.0.0
```